# Is this a mapping of reals (in decimal form) to naturals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been reading that natural numbers are countable (I saw that diagonal thing, from Cantor I think), and reals are uncountable. 
So first of all, I tried mapping reals to natural numbers as follows:

- Start with an integer (I'll use 8)
- Take the first digit to the left
  of the decimal point (use leading zeros if needed)
- Take the first
  digit to the right of the decimal point
- Take the second digit to the left of the decimal point
- Etc

Thus: 5.2 become 852; 0.2121.. becomes 8020102010...; and so forth.
So is this a legitimate one-to-one mapping of reals to naturals? And is it "countable?"

Comment: Nope. There is no natural number $802010\ldots$. Naturals are finite. If it were legitimate, it would be countable, but it isn't, so...

Comment: You don't need a diagonal argument to show the naturals are countable, you're thinking of the rationals. Some define a countable set as one for which there exists an injection into the naturals. The naturals themselves are therefore obviously countable.